# Python stops registering mouse inputs?

Tags: python, winapi, pyhook, pythoncom

I have this code here. I coded this "bot" in order to increase mouse clicks. I've only one issue, python stops registering mouse inputs during that time.sleep (marked with #issue). When I set it to 20/30 ms I can barely notice it, but whenver I try to increase it, it gets more noticeable and annoying, since my cursor completely stops moving. I really don't know where the problem is. Thank you all in advance.

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
from random import randint
import pythoncom, pyHook
import sys

semaphore = False 

def OnMouseLeftUp(event): 
    global semaphore
    if semaphore:
        return True
    semaphore = True

    if randint(0, 24) < 7 :
        time.sleep(float(randint(6,11))/1000)  #issue  
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)


    semaphore = False
    return True



# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# set the hook
hm.HookMouse()
# waits for MouseLeftUp event
hm.MouseLeftUp = OnMouseLeftUp # Triggers OnMouseLeftUp function

# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: So during the time.sleep() function, the code is not  longer running to move the mouse is the issue, cause isn't that the point of the sleep function

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Do you have any possible solution for this issue?